# android 4.2 how to get main color of current theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

In android 4.2 we have the possibility to select theme in device settings.

[image: theme selection]

Default theme is equivalent to using `@android:color/holo_blue_light` as main color.

The question is what tag to use in order to get main color (blue_light, mint, mocha, raspberry) in my own style? If I use `@android:color/holo_blue_light`, when user switches to mint, part of user interface is in mint color (parts not modified by myself) and part in blue_light (parts modified by myself). I spent many many hours and it's seems there is no any solution.... Perhaps any workaround....?

I even tried to analyse Android styles and theme sources and still no answer:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

At the end I'm posting part of my style code (on the request of one users here):

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    </style>
```

Instead of using `@android:color/holo_blue_light` i should use probably something like `@android:color/holo_main_color` but the problem is it seems not to exist.

Comment: please post some code !

Comment: I have android 4.4 (nexus 4) and do not have this option. Where did you find it?

Comment: @mansoulx I added part of my style code, but I don't expect it changes something...

Comment: @poitroae - I click menu button/system settings/display/theme (pure android 4.2.2).

Comment: @user2707175 I do not have this option. 4.4 "pure" Android by Google.I s your phone rooted?

Comment: @poitroae - was it introduced only in android 4.2 and then skipped? as I wan't able to find anything how to get this main color? In theory it's possible that the phone producer added something but in general this android version seems to be pure without any additional options....

Comment: and phone is not rooted....

Comment: This is not found in standard Android, it is a manufacturer customization. What phone do you have?

Comment: it's quite untypical alps a8 made by sonim. But looking on the phone, i wouldn't say it has any non-standard options... or at least not many.... and by the way the idea itself seems to be quite interesting, if it's manufacturer customization, google could add this but of course solving it well - ex. assuring good working with own programmers themes...

Comment: Thank you for all the answers and for help. It seems that it's quite untypical solution and probably it's not even not possible to improve my app in order to work ok with this untypical solution.